# Strings and Immutability

Tags: java

I'm learning about defensive copying.....

I need to ensure that the instance variable a in the example below is immutable. I have no mutator methods in the class, I've forbidden my accessor method from being overridden, and a is private and final.

However, I'm unsure if when I call getA() I need to follow the first or second approach...

Because Strings are immutable, I think the first, but I would really appreciate clarification because immutability is so important and I'm worried about the implications if I get it wrong!

```
 private final String a;


   final String getA() {

      return a;

    }
```

or

```
   final String getA() {

      return new String(letter);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Strings are immutable, there is no need to create a defensive copy of them; it is impossible for them to be modified other than by being replaced entirely by another string. Therefore the first version is correct. In fact, since `a` is a `final` field of an immutable class, it is entirely impossible for `a` to be modified by anyone, and therefore it would be safe to simply make it `public` with no accessor at all: `public final String a`.

Note however that it is entirely unnecessary to declare the method as `final`: non-`final` methods may be overridden by subclasses, which will change the behavior if the method is called, but overriding this method relating to `a` does not give the subclass any more access to `a` than it did before.

Comment: Making `a` public when it is final would be safe from everything, except refactoring.  You put getters on these things incase, for whatever reason, you might someday want to trigger some code whenever `a` is accessed.  By putting a getter on it before hand you force clients of your class to be built in a way that allows for this.  Otherwise changing later means refactoring all those clients.  That's why we do it.  It goes against YAGNI and Tell-Don't-Ask but that's why.  It's the crappiest form of encapsulation but at least it's something.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I decided that the design of whether or not to use an accessor was outside the scope of the question; only the safety was asked.

Comment: @Saposhiente be wary of speaking in absolutes with those still learning.  Sometimes they believe what you say rather than what you mean.

Comment: @CandiedOrange The point is, I said it was safe, not that it was necessarily right.

Answer (score 3):

You have it correct.  By the way, the `final` modifier on the method only means that the method can't be overridden in any subclasses, it doesn't really have anything to do with the immutability of `a`.